# AWS IAM - ELB & RDS - Deny access to certain subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, amazon-elb

I want to create an IAM policy that restricts an AWS IAM role from creating Load Balancers and RDS instances in certain subnets.

I'm looking for something similar like the approaches for [EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_ec2_instances-subnet.html) and [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html), but I haven't found anything for ELB and RDS so far. Does someone have an idea?

My use-case is the following: my AWS setup has six private subnets but three of those are only to be used by a Kubernetes CNI, so they should not be usable by any unrelated services that can spawn resources in subnets.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a iam role with all the required permissions and then remove the ones that are not required(creating load balancer & rds instances ).
Then test that iam role using the below iam policy simulator to check whether it suffice your requirement

https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your answer? For example: action and condition.

Comment: Exactly, examples for actions/conditions/resource would be amazing. I know the general procedure an am already doing it for other use cases. I'm just struggling to find right policies for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i tested a role which denies any action on ELB & RDS resourecs for a specified subnet.

I created a role ( e.g. power role)  which provides all the permission with the policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PowerAdmin",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

I created below policy (denyrdselb) to deny any actions for rds & elb resources for a specific subnet

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DenyRDSELB",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "rds:*",
            "elasticloadbalancing:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "ec2:Subnet": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxx:subnet/subnet-xxxxxx    "
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

I then attached the above policy  as permission boundary to the power user role.

I have tested the policy using policy simulator with or without permission boundary policy .

I was able to take actions related to rds or elb without permission boundary.
But with permission boundry in place I wasn't able to take any actions on rds & elb.

I hope the above can help you in your case as well . You just need to provide list of subnets under conditions and amend actions & resources according to your requirement.

Comment: Did you find the above answer useful ?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your effort. :) I tried it, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Corresponding to that observation the IAM console outputs the warning "There are no actions in your policy that support this condition key." - which is fitting because the "ec2:Subnet" key does seem to be neither be supported by ELB (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonrds.html#amazonrds-policy-keys) nor RDS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_elasticloadbalancing.html).